# what aren't I getting here?

Tags: perl, printing, newline

This one really has me confused and I don't know how to accurately title it.

I am writing a program, the purpose is irrelevant, but some of you may know as I've been asking a few questions about it recently.

I'm going to post the entire program but I don't think that's necessary. The part you need to look at is the nested loops where it says "beginning search algorithm."

The program takes a long time to complete, so after every iteration of the outermost loop, I print a '.'. after every 7 dots a new line is printed. 
for some reason, however no dots will get printed, until a newline is printed.

heres the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.14;
use warnings;
# this is a cgi implementation of a theorum proover.
# the program uses resolution refutation, using a breadth-first and set of support strategy
# to generate a proof(if possible) and relay the results to the user.  

########################################################################################
#Algorithm:
#1.) Get size(i) of knowledge base
#2.) untill you have i clauses
#   3.) get the clause, add to knowledge base
#4.) get the conclusion variable(conjecture)
#5.) add the negation of the conjecture to the knowledge base
#6.) add the negation of the conjecture to the SOS set.
#7.) compare the SOS set to ever other clause
#   8.) if resolution is possible, add the new clause to the knowledge base if it does not already exist. 
#   9.) add the new clause to the SOS set. 
#10.) repeat  7-9 untill the null clause is generated or no more resolution is possible. 
########################################################################################
my $conclusion;
my $conclusion2;
my @conclusion;
my @SOS;
my @clauses;
my $found=0;

#batch mode
if($ARGV[0])
{
    my $filename = $ARGV[0];

    open(IN, "<", $filename);
    chomp(@clauses=<IN>);   
    close(IN);
    for(@clauses)
    {
        $_ =~ s/[^A-Za-z~,]//g;
    }

    #negate the negation to get the desired conclusion for later
    $conclusion2=$clauses[$#clauses];
    print "$conclusion2";
    @conclusion = split("", $conclusion2);

    if($conclusion[0] eq '~')
    {
            splice(@conclusion, 0, 1);
            $found=1;   
    }

    if (!$found)
    {
         $conclusion = "~$conclusion2";
    }
    else
    {
        $conclusion = join("", @conclusion);
    }

    #now break up each line and make @clauses 2d
    $_ = [split /,/ ] for @clauses;

}
#interactive mode
else
{
    my $count=0;

    say "Welcome to my Theorum Proover!";
    say "How many clauses are in your knowledge base?";
    say "(this does not include the conclusion)";
    print "Amount: ";

    my $amt = <>;

    say "Enter your clauses: ";
    say "Negations can be indicated with a '~'.";
    say "Variable names must contain only letters.";
    say "Separate each literal with a ','<br>"; 
    my $clauses;
    while($count < $amt)
    {
        print "clause $count:";
        $clauses .= <>;
        $clauses =~ s/[^A-Za-z~,]//g;
        $clauses .= ";";
        $count++;
        print "\n";
    }


    print "\n \n \n Enter the conclusion, your conclusion should be a literal:";
    $conclusion = <>;   
    $conclusion =~ s/[^A-Za-z~]//g; 
    print "\n";

    #negate the conclusion and add it to the set of clauses. 
    @conclusion = split("", $conclusion);
    if($conclusion[0] eq '~')
    {
        splice(@conclusion, 0, 1);
        $found=1;
    }
    if (!$found)
    {
         $conclusion2 = "~$conclusion";
    }
    else
    {
        $conclusion2 = join("", @conclusion);
    }   

    # split up the contents of the clause string and add them to a 2d array.
    #then, add the negated conclusion to the list.
    my @PartClauses= split(';', $clauses);
    my $last=@PartClauses;
    for my $i (0 .. $#PartClauses)
    {
        my @tmp=split(',', $PartClauses[$i]);
        for my $j (0 .. @tmp)
        {
            $clauses[$i][$j] = $tmp[$j];
        }

    }   
    $clauses[$last][0] = $conclusion2;
}



open(RESULTS, ">", 'results.txt');
for my $i (0 .. $#clauses)
{
    print RESULTS "clause $i: {";
    for my $j (0 .. $#{ $clauses[$i] })
    {

        print RESULTS "$clauses[$i][$j]";


        if($j != $#{ $clauses[$i] })
        {
            print RESULTS ",";
        }

    }
    print RESULTS "}\n";
}
print RESULTS "_____________________________\n";


print "Beginning search ....";

##################################################
#begin breadthfirst/sos search/add algorithm
$SOS[0][0]=$conclusion2;
my $cSize=$#clauses;
say "\nworking......";

my $sAdd=0;
my $cAdd=0; 
my $res=0;
my $flag=0;
my $dots=0;
SOSROW:
for (my $a=0; $a<=$#SOS; $a++)
{

    &update;
    CLAUSEROW:
    for (my $i=0; $i<=$#clauses; $i++)
    {
        SOSCOL:
        for (my $b=0; $b<=$#{ $SOS[$a] }; $b++)
        {
            CLAUSECOL:  
            for my $j (0 .. $#{ $clauses[$i] })
            {
                if($SOS[$a][$b] eq "~$clauses[$i][$j]"
                || $clauses[$i][$j] eq "~$SOS[$a][$b]")
                {
                    my @tmp;
                    #found a resolution, so add all other literals from
                    #both clauses to each set as a single clause

                    #start with the SOS literals(use a hash to keep track of duplicates)
                    my %seen;
                    for my $x (0 .. $#{ $SOS[$a] })
                    {
                        if($x != $b)
                        {
                            $seen{$SOS[$a][$x]}=1; 
                            push @tmp, "$SOS[$a][$x]";              
                        }
                    }
                    #now add the literals from the non-SOS clause
                    for my $y (0 .. $#{ $clauses[$i] })
                    {
                        if($y != $j)
                        {
                            if(! $seen{ $clauses[$i][$y] })
                            {
                                push(@tmp, "$clauses[$i][$y]");
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    #check to see if the clause is already listed
                    my $dupl = 0;
                    my @a1 = sort(@tmp);
                    my $s1 = join("", @a1);
                    MATCH:
                    for my $i (0 .. $#clauses)
                    {
                        my @a2= sort(@{ $clauses[$i] });
                        my $s2= join("", @a2);                          
                        if($s1 eq $s2 )
                        { 
                            $dupl = 1;
                            last MATCH; 
                        }
                    }

                    #if it isn't, go ahead and add it in
                    if(! $dupl)
                    {
                        $res++;
                        $sAdd++;
                        $cAdd++;
                        my $s = $cSize + $cAdd;
                        push(@SOS, \@tmp);
                        push(@clauses, \@tmp);
                        #print out the new clauses.
                        print RESULTS"clause $s: ";
                        my $clause = $cSize+$a;                 
                        print RESULTS "{";
                        if($SOS[$sAdd][0])
                        {
                            for my $j(0 .. $#{ $clauses[$s] })
                            {

                                if($clauses[$s][$j])
                                {
                                    print RESULTS "$clauses[$s][$j]";
                                }

                                if($j!= $#{ $clauses[$s] })
                                {
                                    print RESULTS ",";
                                }

                            }       
                            print RESULTS "} ($i,$clause)\n";
                        }
                        #if you found a new res, but there was nothing to push, you found
                        # the contradiction, so signal and break.   
                        else 
                        {   
                        print RESULTS "} ($i,$clause)\n";
                            $flag=1;
                            last SOSROW;
                        }   
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}   

close(RESULTS);
if($flag)
{
    say "After $res resolutions, a resolvent was found and the empty set was generated."; 
    say "This indicates that when '$conclusion' is false, the entire knowledge base is false."; 
    say "Because we know that the clauses in the knowledge base are actually true, we can soundly conclude that '$conclusion must also be true.";
    say "The clauses generated by each resolution can be found below.\n\n"; 
}
else
{
    say "We were not able to generate the empty clause.";
    say "this means that adding the negation of the desired conclusion does not render the theorum false.";
    say "Therefore, we can not safely conclude that '$conclusion' is true.";  
    say "Any clauses that we were able to generate through a resoluton can be viewed below.\n\n";
}
print `more results.txt`;

sub update
{
    if((($dots % 7) == 0))
    {
        print "\n";
    }
    if($dots==14)
    {
        print "You might want to get some coffee.\n"; 
    }

    if($dots==35)
    {
        print "I'm being VERY Thorough.\n";
    }

    if($dots==63 || $dots==140)
    {
        print "Hows that coffee?\n";
    }
    if($dots==105)
    {
        print "I think it might be time for a second cup of coffee\n"
    }
    if($dots==210)
    {
        print "Like I said, VERY thorough\n";
    }
    if($dots==630)
    {
        print "My O is bigger than you can imagine\n"
    }
    $dots++;
    print ".";
}
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. could it have something to do with buffering?

If instead of calling the subroutine, i just say print "."; nothing will be printed until, the prog finishes execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, filehandles are buffered by default. If `STDOUT` points to a terminal it will be line-buffered (nothing is output until a newline is printed), otherwise it will be block-buffered (nothing is output until a certain number of bytes is printed). The easiest way to change that is to set `$|=1`, which will make the current output filehandle (usually `STDOUT` unbuffered), so it will flush after every `print`.